# How to paste with keyboard in test Android studio

Tags: android, android-espresso

Im trying to use the paste function when I longclick on a text input and the "paste" option appears. I have tried to click with

```
onView(withText("Paste"))
            .perform(click(), pressImeActionButton());
```

using espresso but it does not work. How can i click the little paste prompt that appears?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you were asking for but given that I don't think it's possible to do this with Espresso you might consider doing (ctrl + v) to perform paste in UIAutomator in your tests:

```
UiDevice
    .getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
    .pressKeyCode(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_V, KeyEvent.META_CTRL_MASK)
```

You might want to have a look at the [Espresso & UIAutomator - the perfect tandem](https://testyour.app/blog/espresso-uiautomator) article.